# How to get refund on tatkal waitlisted ticket?

Tags: trains, tickets, india, indian-railways, tatkal

Do I have to cancel the the waitlisted tatkal ticket to get refund or will it get refunded automatically without any cancellation of ticket?

Comment: If it remains W/L till chart preparation then you will get the refund(minus service charges) assuming you booked online. But if you can cancel it explicitly online then you should do it because remember that once confirmed then you wont get anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you have booked your ticket through online and if it is W/L till chat preparation then amount will be refunded automatically to your account from which you have paid. 
If you have booked it from any railway counter then you have to go there and cancel there itself.